# Accessing from one method to another in .net with url

Tags: .net-core

I'm new to .net and I'm working on a project.
I need to do an integration for 2 factor authentication.
After logging in, I need to give the url it will return to. It checks in `saml.authrequest` and if the login is successful, it returns the specified url.
I do the redirect for login with this method:

```
[HttpPost, ODataRoute("Authtake")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseLogin), Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ResponseLogin), Status400BadRequest)]
    public string Authtake()
    {

        addres = _config["SSOAddress"].ToString();
        addres2 = _config["SiteAddress"].ToString();
        entityID = _config["EntityID"].ToString();
        samlCertificate = _config["Cert"].ToString();


        var request = new Saml.AuthRequest(entityID, "https://" + addres2 + "/xxx");


        string url = request.GetRedirectUrl("https://" + addres + "xxxx");
        return url.ToString();

    }
```

I need to reach the other method from this method with the url in the x part ("/xxx").
Method to go:

```
public IActionResult SAML(string SAMLResponse, string RelayState)
    {

        Saml.Response samlResponse = new Saml.Response(samlCertificate);
        samlResponse.LoadXmlFromBase64(Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]);
        string username = samlResponse.GetEmail().ToLowerInvariant();
        return Ok();
    }
```

how can i access this method with url from previous method?